# slow processing of hive on self join

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, hive, query-optimization

I have a hive table in which i am doing a self join and  joining on the basis of ip and differentiating on name and  subtracting the date which is in string format by using unix_timestamp to convert it into seconds and subtract the time.But it is taking lot of time.

```
Create table t1 (a_name string,a_Code bigint,a_Time string,
a_Ipaddress string, b_name string,b_Code bigint,b_TIME string,b_Ipaddress
string,date1 string) 
STORED as RCFILE;

INSERT INTO TABLE NETWORK_Sharing 
SELECT n1.a_name,n1.a_Code,n1.a_TIME ,n1.a_Ipaddress,n2.b_name ,n2.b_Code,n2.b_TIME,
n2.b_Ipaddress,n1.date1 from t n1 JOIN t n2
ON (n1.a_Ipaddress=n2.b_Ipaddress) 
where n1.a_name <> n2.b_name AND
(unix_timestamp(n1.a_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') -
unix_timestamp(n2.b_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) <= 300 AND
(unix_timestamp(n1.TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') -
unix_timestamp(n2.TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) >= 0;
```

Comment: how many rows does each ip address have in `t`?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid a self-join, if at all possible, and use a collect to perform an aggregation rather than a join.  Check out this blog post which discusses a similar use-case ( http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-collect-to-avoid-the-self-join/ )

In your case, you basically want to see if two events are occurring at the same time, so it might be a little trickier.  What about something like

```
CREATE TABLE t1 
AS
SELECT Ipaddress, 
     cast( TIME/300 as bigint ) as EVENT_TIME_BUCKET,
     collect( name ) as NAMES,
     collect( code ) as CODES
     collect( TIME ) as TIMES
FROM t
GROUP BY 
   IpAddress, cast(TIME/300 as bigint)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I guess you might want to have a larger time bucket of 600, depending on your use case,
 and eliminate the rows which don't match your criteria. ( ie. something like 
 WHERE ! (  size( TIMES) == 2 AND array_index( TIMES, 1 ) - array_index(TIMES, 0 ) > 300) 
) but your actual query or threshold would depend upon your data set.